# Google map set Center

Tags: google-maps, java-me

I am building program that displays location of many people. How can I set the Center so it shows all the locations?

This is my code but I need to zoom out to see other locations

```
gMaps = new GoogleMaps();

map = gMaps.createMap(getWidth(), getHeight(), GoogleStaticMap.FORMAT_PNG);

map.setHandler(this);

map.setCenter(new GoogleMapsCoordinates(24.71167 ,46.72417));
```

Comment: Are you using the MidMaps library, or what?

Answer (score 1):

This can be achieved by using the fitBounds() method. Check out the [Google Maps v3 API reference](http://code.google.com/apis/maps/documentation/javascript/reference.html).

Small example:

```
//set viewport
var viewport = new google.maps.LatLngBounds();
viewport.extend(p1);
viewport.extend(p2);

//center map using active markers
map.fitBounds(viewport);
```

In that example, p1 and p2 are coordinates (lat,lng).

Comment: thanks but i do not know how to use java script is there another way

Comment: @andufo, looks like he's using Java ME, but your code is for Javascript API 3

Comment: i only have used javascript for google maps api, still those methods should be available for java.

Comment: how can i add the javascript in javame project

Comment: you can't. what you should do, is check whether the LatLngBounds  class and fitBounds method are available on the static maps for java (I don't know that, since I've only used the javascript version of the API). According to this, you do have this available: http://code.google.com/p/gwt-google-apis/source/browse/trunk/google-apis/src/com/google/gwt/maps/client/geom/LatLngBounds.java?r=41

Comment: thanks i am using this ipa http://www.jappit.com/j2me/midmaps/javadocs/ but it look like it do not support it

Comment: @andufo how to load lat and lng bound dynamically if we dont know number of objects? I am using php to get objects

Comment: @denonth by objects you mean the points? Just add all the available points to the viewport object and the fitBounds() will take care of that automatically.

Comment: @andufo Yes I meant points. So I read points that I need and I put it in the php array an the put an array into the var viewport=php array... Is that what you meant?

Comment: @denoth exactly. You can include as many points as you wish. The fitBounds() method will make sure that all are included in the view.